# IronPython script with Sympy

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, sympy

Now I'm getting error:
Server Error in Application. Cannot import name typed Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: Cannot import name typed Source Error: Line 44: expr)); Line 45: Line 46: script.Execute(scope); Line 48: return scope.GetVariable("result");

```
public static string PythonEvaluate(string expr) 
{ 
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

    paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\Site-Packages");
    paths.Add(@"C:\sympy");
    engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

    var scope = engine.CreateScope();

    var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(string.Format(@"
                import sys
                sys.platform = "win32"  // Default is cli

                from sympy import *
                n = Symbol('n')
                value = {0}

                import clr
                from System import String
                result = clr.Convert(value , String)",
            expr));

    script.Execute(scope);  

    return scope.GetVariable("result");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = PythonEvaluate("limit((1 + 3/n)**n, n, oo)");
    Label3.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Tell us what the error messages are.

Comment: By the way, SymPy hasn't been officially tested in IronPython, so the issue could just be that it doesn't really work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, it's impossible to tell what's wrong of you don't tell us what the error is, but a possibility is that you are using `limit` incorrectly. You need to pass it a symbolic object, not a lambda function, it takes three arguments, and infinity is called ,`oo`, not `inf`.

```
n = Symbol("n")
limit((1 + 3/n)**n, n, oo)
```

Comment: i changed my code with checking whitespacing then i tried your solution i get this error do you have any idea ?No module named fcntl

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named fcntl

Source Error: 


Line 39: result = clr.Convert(value, String)", expr));
Line 40: 
Line 41:     script.Execute(scope);
Line 42: 
Line 43:     return scope.GetVariable("result");

Comment: Can you run `import sympy` from the iron python shell?

Comment: I get that too.  I think this is a bug in IronPython.  Try doing `import subprocess` (note that this is part of the Python standard library).

Comment: And by the way, what platform are you on?

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: From what I can tell, this comes from the `subprocess` module not correctly seeing that you are in windows (this happens to me because I am using Mono on Mac OS X).  In IronPython, do `import sys;sys.platform`. If it's not "win32", you might fix the problem by adding `import sys; sys.platform = "win32"` at the top of your code. Alternately, if your `sys.platform` is set to "cli", you can fix it by setting `os.name` to "nt".

Answer (score 3):

I’m not familar with executing Python code in .NET, but in Python every indent has a meaning. I’d guess that you need to remove all leading whitespace for the code:

```
    // ...
    var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(string.Format(@"
from sympy import *
value = {0}

import clr
from System import String
result = clr.Convert(value , String)", expr));

    script.Execute(scope);
```

Comment: @user1940128 Still the same error? Is there really no whitespace in front of those lines? Also does the `@"` line have any *trailing* whitespace?

Comment: when i add them as a single line , i get this error script.Execute(scope);  = > unexpected token 'value'

Comment: @user1940128 Well, you can’t really write Python in a single line. Whitespace, including line breaks, is important. Can you try adding `\n` linebreaks manually, but keep the string otherwise in a single line? (You need to remove the `@` from the string literal though to make the escape sequence work)

Comment: i tried with using white space but i still have the same problem.